# HTML booking form date field showing PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've implemented this HTML/JS booking form which displays fine on chrome but in firefox and IE11 it doesn't: [This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBzW9.png)

And this is the code

```
<form action="http://ilfracombecarlton.co.uk/newsite/book/" method="get">
```

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="col-1-4 col-1-4-sm">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="date" id="arrive" class="floatLabel" name="checkInDate" value="<?php echo date('M d, Y'); ?>" />
    <label for="arrive" class="label-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Arrive</label>
  </div>      
</div>
<div class="col-1-4 col-1-4-sm">
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="date" id="depart" class="floatLabel" name="checkOutDate" value="<?php echo date('M d, Y'); ?>" />
    <label for="depart" class="label-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Depart</label>
  </div>      
</div>
   <div class="col-1-4 col-1-4-sm">
  <div class="controls">
    <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
    <select class="floatLabel" id="noOfAdultOpt" name="noOfAdult">
      <option value="blank"></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2" selected>2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <label for="fruit"><i class="fa fa-male"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;People</label>
  </div>      
</div>
 <div style="display:none" class="col-1-4 col-1-4-sm">
  <div class="controls">
    <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
    <select class="floatLabel" id="noOfChildOpt">
      <option value="blank"></option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2" selected>2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <label for="fruit"><i class="fa fa-male"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Children</label>
  </div>      
</div>
 <div class="col-1-4 col-1-4-sm">
  <button type="submit"  value="checkMyValues()"  class="col-1-4">Check availability</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The form works correctly in all browsers, it's just a display issue. Could you please point me in the right direction.
Thank you all 
gp

Comment: You have a space between the `<?` and `php`. That's a no-no. Your closing tag is backwards, too. Also a no-no.

Comment: this isn't a serverside issue if that isn't `<? php` but `<?php`. is that a typo? bad paste? If anything, you'd be getting a parse error.

Comment: Post your code here but first error I see is <?php , you have <? php

Comment: Syntax is wrong for your tags

   (<? php echo date ('M d, Y'); >?)
Turn that into

(<?php echo date ('M d, Y'); ?>).

Comment: PHP isn't being parsed on initlal page load.

Comment: Chrome throws a warning in the console as well, the code is not printed as it doesn't match the field's pattern. PHP is not being parsed.

Comment: Look at your developer console, you'll find your answer; there are errors.

Answer (score -1):

`<? php echo date ('M d, Y'); >?` Wrong Tags placement. Kindly change to this `=( <?php echo date ('M d, Y'); ?>)`